# Undefined property: stdClass::$delaInstitucion Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, undefined

Buenas al ejecutar el método search en la vista me sale este error
y me dice que la propiedad no esta definida? . LA vista carga bien y antes de poner la relación que trae el dato del nombre de la institución el metodo de buscar funcionaba de maravillas

[image: Esta es mi vista]

El controlador esta así

```
 public function search(Request $request) {
    $search = $request->get('search');
    $estudiantes = DB::table('estudiantes')
            ->where('idEstudiante', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')   ->paginate(5);
    return view('BaseDatos/estudiantes.index', ["estudiantes" => $estudiantes]);
}
```

El modelo es este

```
public function institucion() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Siginemeta1\Institucion');
}

public function delaInstitucion()
{
     return $this->hasOne('Siginemeta1\Institucion','id','institucion_id');   
}
```

y la vista es

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="/search" method="get">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class='btn btn-warning'>Buscar</button>
                </span>
            </div>                    
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
    @include('flash::message')
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                <thead>
                <th>Numero de Identificacion</th>
                <th>Institucion</th>
                <th>Primer Apellido</th>
                <th>Segundo Apellido</th>
                <th>Primer Nombre</th>
                <th>Segundo Nombre</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
                <th>Año de Ingreso</th>
                <th>Ver</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
                </thead>
                @foreach ($estudiantes as $estudiante)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$estudiante->idEstudiante}}</td>
                    <td>{{$estudiante->delaInstitucion->nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{$estudiante->apellido1}}</td>
                    <td>{{$estudiante->apellido2}}</td>
                    <td>{{$estudiante->nombre1}}</td>
                    <td>{{$estudiante->nombre2}}</td>
                    <td>{{$estudiante->email}}</td>
                    <td>{{$estudiante->añoIngreso}}</td>
                    <td>    
                        <a href="{{route('estudiantes.show', $estudiante->id)}}"><button class="btn-sm btn-success btn-lg fa fa-eye">  </button></a>

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <form action="{{route('estudiantes.destroy',$estudiante->id)}}"method="POST">
                            @csrf
                            @method('DELETE')
                            <button  type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-danger btn-lg fa fa-trash" onclick="return confirm('Seguro! Desea borrar este registro?')" > </button>
                        </form>

                    </td>

                </tr>
                @endforeach
```

El problema parece estar en la vista pero no logro saber cual es?
Se da cuando ejecuto la opción Buscar. Método search

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo la consulta con el Query Builder, con lo cual obtendrás una colección de arrays.

```
$estudiantes = DB::table('estudiantes')
        ->where('idEstudiante', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')   ->paginate(5);
```

Si deseas cargar las relaciones de un modelo como propiedades dinámicas, deberás utilizar Eloquent.

Asumiendo que la tabla estudiantes tenga un modelo App\Estudiante, la consulta sería así:

```
$estudiantes = Estudiante::where('idEstudiante', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->paginate(5);
```

No olvides incluir el modelo al comienzo:

```
use App\Estudiante;
```

Comment: sos grande capo, gracias